# pymongo "UnicodeEncodeError" with Python 3.x

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode, python-requests, pymongo

*EDIT: I realize the title might be a bit confusing, but the problem applies both to the API data AND the data in MongoDB when using Python 3.X*

I've been playing around with MongoDB, pymongo, and newsapi.org to get some comfort with nosql, but I've been having some unicode issues. In the below code, I'm simply following the demo provided by newsapi.org to pull down the json formatted data, and had no trouble inserting the results in my collection when using Python 2.X.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import json

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'q=Apple&'
       'from=2017-11-27&'
       'sortBy=popularity&'
       'apiKey=')

response = requests.get(url)

cursor = db.news_api.find({'_id': ObjectId('5a1c8e3b49318f67f6a85cc9')})

for i in cursor:
    pprint(i)
    print(i['description'].encode('utf-8'))
```

This refused to work when I used Python 3.X, giving me the error below:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 6: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Additionally, when I query the data I was able to load using Python 3.X, I get the same issue (which I guess makes sense). I don't know a ton about encoding, but Python 2.X appears to be able to handle this unicode just fine:

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

cursor = db.news_api.find({'_id': ObjectId('5a1c8e3b49318f67f6a85cc9')})

for i in cursor:
    pprint(i)
    print(i['description'].encode('utf-8'))
```

RESULT:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('5a1c8e3b49318f67f6a85cc9'),
 u'author': u'Jacob Kleinman',
 u'description': u'Apple\u2019s Home app makes it easy to control all your smart home tech right from your iPhone, but because this is Apple we\u2019re dealing with, it also comes with some restrictions. The biggest drawback is that Home only works with a small subset of HomeKit -approve\u2026',
 u'publishedAt': u'2017-11-27T21:30:00Z',
 u'source': {u'id': None, u'name': u'Lifehacker.com'},
 u'title': u'How to Control Unapproved Smart Home Gadgets with Apple\u2019s HomeKit',
 u'url': u'https://lifehacker.com/how-to-control-unapproved-smart-home-gadgets-with-apple-1820775984',
 u'urlToImage': u'https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--0DEjQU0x--/c_fill,fl_progressive,g_center,h_450,q_80,w_800/ghm8a2bwmjscjign0d2c.png'}
Apple’s Home app makes it easy to control all your smart home tech right from your iPhone, but because this is Apple we’re dealing with, it also comes with some restrictions. The biggest drawback is that Home only works with a small subset of HomeKit -approve…
```

So what exactly is going on here? Why is 2.X fine with this data but not 3.X? Is there any way around this at the time of scraping the site?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Full error message:

```
{'author': 'Jacob Kleinman',
 'description': ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-183af792a13b> in <module>()
      1 for i in response.json()['articles']:
----> 2         pprint(i)
      3         print(type(i))
      4

/home/kemri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pprint.py in pprint(object, stream, indent, width, depth, compact)
     51         stream=stream, indent=indent, width=width, depth=depth,
     52         compact=compact)
---> 53     printer.pprint(object)
     54
     55 def pformat(object, indent=1, width=80, depth=None, *, compact=False):

/home/kemri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pprint.py in pprint(self, object)
    137
    138     def pprint(self, object):
--> 139         self._format(object, self._stream, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    140         self._stream.write("\n")
    141

/home/kemri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    165             if p is not None:
    166                 context[objid] = 1
--> 167                 p(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level + 1)
    168                 del context[objid]
    169                 return

/home/kemri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pprint.py in _pprint_dict(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    187             items = sorted(object.items(), key=_safe_tuple)
    188             self._format_dict_items(items, stream, indent, allowance + 1,
--> 189                                     context, level)
    190         write('}')
    191

/home/kemri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pprint.py in _format_dict_items(self, items, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    344             self._format(ent, stream, indent + len(rep) + 2,
    345                          allowance if last else 1,
--> 346                          context, level)
    347             if not last:
    348                 write(delimnl)

/home/kemri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    165             if p is not None:
    166                 context[objid] = 1
--> 167                 p(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level + 1)
    168                 del context[objid]
    169                 return

/home/kemri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pprint.py in _pprint_str(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    287             if i > 0:
    288                 write('\n' + ' '*indent)
--> 289             write(rep)
    290         if level == 1:
    291             write(')')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 6: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: OS?  What is the full traceback, which will show what line is failing?  I suspect you are on Linux, and your terminal is configured to support `latin-1` instead of UTF-8.  Python 2, when printing a dictionary, won't print non-ASCII to the terminal (for example, `u'Apple\u2019s'`), but Python 3 will (`u'Apple’s'`).  Check your `LANG` environment setting.  `latin-1` doesn't support that character.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I added the full traceback (running Python 3.) and can also verify that my Linux environment is configured for UTF-8.